# heroku node js create folder issue

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, directory, path

I have express app which works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to heroku it doesn't create any folders, although all other functionality works fine

in order to specify the path to the file i use nodejs path and save it to mongoDB

How it looks on **Localhost:5000** after uploading file inside project:

[image]

**MongoDB file path field**:

C:\Users\inbec\OneDrive\New folder\Documents\Code\servers\CooperateFront-back\files/60f063de9e95e729f05dfcfb/60f0642b9e95e729f05dfd02/60f064369e95e729f05dfd07/Screenshot_3.png

How it looks with **Heroku**:

Heroku CLI: `heroku run bash -a cooperatefront-back`

```
~/files $ cd 60f063de9e95e729f05dfcfb
bash: cd: 60f063de9e95e729f05dfcfb: No such file or directory
```

**In Browser:**

> Cannot GET
> /app/files/60f063de9e95e729f05dfcfb/60f05fe09d17a600223700d7/60f05fe59d17a600223700db/Screenshot_1.png

**MongoDB file path field**: /app/files/60f063de9e95e729f05dfcfb/60f05fe09d17a600223700d7/60f05fe59d17a600223700db/Screenshot_1.png

**index.js**

```
app.use(filePathMiddleWare(path.resolve(__dirname, "files")))
app.use(fileUpload({}))


app.use("/files",express.static("files"))
```

**filepath-middleware:**

```
function filePath(path) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        req.filePath = path
        next()
    }
}

module.exports = filePath
```

**FileService:**

```
class FileService {
    createDor(req,file) {
        console.log(req.filePath, "filePath")
        const filePath = `${req.filePath}\\${file.user}\\${file.path}`
        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
                    fs.mkdirSync(filePath)
                    return resolve({message: "File was created"})
                } else {
                    return reject({message: "File already exists"})
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
                return reject({message: "File error"})
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found ussue:

no need to specify the **/app** folder to get file

{myHerokuSite}/files/60f06d3f41e750002225c04a/60f06d4641e750002225c051/60f06d4c41e750002225c055/photo_2021-02-22_09-33-17.jpg

*and just in case changed \\ to /*

const filePath = `${req.filePath}\\${file.user}\\${file.path}` =>
`${req.filePath}/${file.user}/${file.path}`

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already answerd your own question here but just be aware that Heroku is essentially a CASS service (container as a service)

This means ephemeral storage is not persistent. Each time you restart, redeploy all items will be lost.

A better approach would be do use an object store like S3. This will allow you to store the images on a persistent volume that will allow your application to keep working even with restarts as the code runs on the container and dynamic / user create assets will be stored in the object store and shared across all running instances.